# Microfocus animator says "perform level=01" even though the program it is presently in is a subprogram and called from another program

Tags: cobol, microfocus

I am facing a problem while debugging a COBOL program, When using animator and when a call is made to another COBOL program with a CALL ... USING statement.

After entering the sub program and pressing P (for Perform) E (for Exit). The animator asks **"Perform Level = 1 Zoom to calling program ?"**, and on pressing Y(for Yes) Animator shows the message **"Perform Level 1"**, and doesn't proceed to the the next line in the calling program (i.e, MAIN.COB) .

The only option available then is to Zoom all along which is not helping much during debugging.

Is there a runtime Switch or a Compiler option to make animator pass the control back to the calling program

Example:
This is the main program that iam debugging

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. MAIN.

DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 WS-STUDENT-ID PIC 9(4) VALUE 1000.
   01 WS-STUDENT-NAME PIC A(15) VALUE 'Tim'.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   CALL 'UTIL' USING WS-STUDENT-ID, WS-STUDENT-NAME.
   DISPLAY 'Student Id : ' WS-STUDENT-ID
   DISPLAY 'Student Name : ' WS-STUDENT-NAME
STOP RUN.
```

This is the called program, UTIL,

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. UTIL.

DATA DIVISION.
   LINKAGE SECTION.
   01 LS-STUDENT-ID PIC 9(4).
   01 LS-STUDENT-NAME PIC A(15).

PROCEDURE DIVISION USING LS-STUDENT-ID, LS-STUDENT-NAME.
   DISPLAY 'In Called Program'.
   MOVE 1111 TO LS-STUDENT-ID.
EXIT PROGRAM.
```

So when iam debugging **MAIN** program, and pass control to **UTIL** subroutine (by **P**erform and **S**tep ). when i try to return back to calling program MAIN, animator gives the message **"Perform Level = 1 Zoom to calling program ? Y/N"** - when i press **Y** is shows a message at lower left saying ""Perform Level = 1" and doesnt skip to the program **MAIN**

When we look at the Perform / Call stack ( by pressing **P** and **V** ) animator displays the below Stack view

```
Perform/Call Stack View-----------------------------------
Program Name                    Section Name
----------------------------------------------------------
UTIL.int                        No Section or Paragraph


---------------------------------------------------------
Zoon    Scroll <so on... >
---------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, only the Sub module is visible in the stack. Whereas it should have been.

```
Perform/Call Stack View-----------------------------------
Program Name                    Section Name
----------------------------------------------------------
UTIL.int                        No Section or Paragraph
MAIN.int                        No Section or Paragraph

---------------------------------------------------------
Zoon    Scroll <so on... >
---------------------------------------------------------
```

(i.e., The calling point from the MAIN.int should also be visible)
This is why i suspect it has something to do with some missing compilation option or Environment settings

Comment: I have been unable to reproduce the problem with my system. Would you be so kind as to supply a minimal program that has the behavior, so I can test it. Also please identify the version of Micro Focus COBOL you are using. You might also try `S` for Step to the next line or, if you aren't debugging the called program, use `P` then `S` (Perform Step) at the `CALL`.

Comment: Thank you, have added a sample code , but i feel its because of some configuration i have that is causing the problem, some setting or environment variable that is making animator ignore adding calling programs' statements to the Perform stack

Comment: What is the output of **P**erform-Level -> **V**iew?

Comment: As soon as i enter UTIL.COB and press P -> V, it shows UTIL.int No sections or Paragraphs.

Comment: I am troubled by "pass control to UTIL subroutine (by Perform and Step )". This is no different than Step. On my system, Perform Step at the `CALL` statement executes `UTIL` with the current line being the statement after the `CALL` in `MAIN`. There are no compiler options or Animator directives, on my system, that would affect Perform Exit as you have described.

Comment: yes, **P**erform **S**tep doesn't cause an issue as animator is not displaying the **UTIL** program's code, so the issue iam facing will not be evident....problem comes when i enter **UTIL** and  then try to come out of it to continue debugging code in **MAIN**